# Python - Storing part of JSON response as a Comma Separated String

Tags: python, json, database, python-2.7

I have a JSON response string that contains the results from scans from multiple antivirus sites. It looks something like -

```
"scans": {
  "Bkav": {
    "detected": false,
    "version": "1.3.0.9466",
    "result": null,
    "update": "20180609"
  },
  "MicroWorld-eScan": {
    "detected": true,
    "version": "14.0.297.0",
    "result": "W97M.Downloader.AIU",
    "update": "20180611"
  },
  "CMC": {
    "detected": false,
    "version": "1.1.0.977",
    "result": null,
    "update": "20180610"
  },
  "CAT-Quickheal": {
    "detected": true,
    "version": "14.00",
    "result": "X97M.Dropper.PD",
    "update": "20180611"
  },
  "McAfee": {
    "detected": true,
    "version": "6.0.6.653",
    "result": "X97M/Downloader.asi",
    "update": "20180611"
  },
},
"tags": {
...
},
```

How can I extract all the non-empty results (all the results that are not null) from the `scans` tag in this JSON and store it into a single comma separated string in a table column of my database?

Thanks!

Comment: You already said what you should do, did you write any code and faced a problem?

Comment: @ARMAN I don't know how exactly  to traverse the JSON string and loop through the scans to get only the not null values.

Comment: Maybe check each field and if it was not `null` save it in new JSON ?

Comment: Would something like this work - `results = []`
        `for scan in r['scans']:`
            `if scan['result'] != 'null':`
                `results.append(scan['result'])`

Comment: It's unclear to me what exactly is the "single comma separated string" that you want. But in general you will need to 2 Python packages `json` and `csv`. The package `json` loads the JSON string into a Python dict. The `csv` package write lists as rows of CSV. You write code to map the dict to a list.

Comment: that's a good start , go on and if you had an error that you couldn't handle it yourself tell us.

Comment: Once you load the JSON into Python dict, you will use `'result' in scan` to check if a field is null in a dict. `scan['result'] != 'null'` likely doesn't work unless null is hard-coded into the string literal "null" in the original JSON.

Comment: Something like this - `none_items = {"null", "[]"}`  `[None if item in none_items else item for item in scan['result']` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably a more efficient way but I think this should give you the comma-separated string value you're after:

```
import json

scans = response_data.get('scans', [])
scan_results = (scans[key]['result'] for key in scans.keys())
csv = ', '.join((result for result in scan_results if result is not None))
```

Comment: Or `', '.join(filter(None, scan_results))`.

Answer (score 1):

Is it the response really JSON?
as I know, JSON cannot be separated by semicolons.
It should be Like below.

```
"scans": {
  "Bkav": {
    "detected": false,
    "version": "1.3.0.9466",
    "result": null,
    "update": "20180609"
  },
  "MicroWorld-eScan": {
    "detected": true,
    "version": "14.0.297.0",
    "result": "W97M.Downloader.AIU",
    "update": "20180611"
  },
  "CMC": {
    "detected": false,
    "version": "1.1.0.977",
    "result": null,
    "update": "20180610"
  },
  "CAT-Quickheal": {
    "detected": true,
    "version": "14.00",
    "result": "X97M.Dropper.PD",
    "update": "20180611"
  },
  "McAfee": {
    "detected": true,
    "version": "6.0.6.653",
    "result": "X97M/Downloader.asi",
    "update": "20180611"
  },
},
"tags": {
...
},
```

After you load JSON to python dict, you can do something like below.

```
import json

jsonDict = json.loads(yourJSON)

results = []
for scanElement in jsonDict['scans']:
    if scanElement['result'] != None:
        results.append(scanElement['result'])

##save the results to your DB
```

Comment: Sorry, yeah that was supposed to be a comma. Thanks! I'll try this out!